# Детский садик — тоже, что и Детский сад?

Tags: фразеология

> Новый детский садик в микрорайоне. Детский садик «Солнышко».

Детский сад, садик (прост.), на глазах превращается в «Детский садик». Возникают вопросы: общий — о необходимости/ненужности, а другой — по характеру — это тоже фразеологизм, или даже тот же?

Comment: Он и зарегистрирован с таким видовым наименованием? Или пока его так рекламируют?

Comment: Это — укороченные цитаты из разных источников. Лишь как иллюстрации.

Answer (score 1):

Садиками называют **частные детские сады** с небольшой численностью детей, другое название  ― **домашний детский сад.**

Пример: Детский садик "Умка". Адрес: г. Москва, ул. Симоновский Вал, д. 14

Детские садики в Москве https://www.molbulak.ru/news/novosti-migratsii/detskie-sadiki-v-moskve/

Comment: «... частных детских садов в городе Москва» и «... государственных детских садиков не хватает»,— это не этой же статьи?

Comment: Кстати о микрорайоне «Майском»: "Здание будет строиться по типовому проекту и рассчитано на 250 мест. Аналогичные сады в настоящий момент есть в Уютном, Радужном и Телецентре". Небольшая численность. https://newtambov.ru/news/novyj-detskij-sadik-v-mikrorajone-majskij-namereny-nachat-stroit-uzhe-v-etom-godu/

Comment: В статье могут использоваться разные названия для частных и государственных садиков и садов, важно то, как  действительно называется детское учреждение. И вот, как мы можем видеть, "детский садик" может быть официальным названием. Государственный детский сад - это образовательное учреждение стандартного типа, а частный сад должен получить аккредитацию и лицензию  (там указаны устав, образовательная программа и пр.).

Comment: Да я Вас понял.